# Reindexing Values

Tags: c++, unordered-map, adjacency-matrix

I am new to C++ programming and have an assignment where a file with a set of values is taken in and used to create an adjacency graph.
The .txt file is like so

```
1 3 22.5
3 1 22.5
8 5 14.2
3 5 2.5
```

The instructor is asking us to use an Unordered Map, but I don't know how to use it for reindexing the first two int values (the float value is distance between the nodes). Can I iterate and fill the map with the values? If so, how?

expected results would be:

```
0 - 1
1 - 3
2 - 5
3 - 8
```

Any tips are much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain your expected results? It is not clear what the two columns of your expected results mean. What does `3 - 8` mean?Also, clarify whether the graph edges given are for a directed graph or an undirected one.

Comment: Oops I thought i wrote in the column types. The left row would be the reindexed number and the right is the corresponding value coming in from the .txt file. Finally, using the reindexed values 0,1....n (left side) make an undirected adj. matrix.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. Is it necessary to re-index the vertices in increasing order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use an `unordered_map` to re-index the vertex values.

**Note:** I am not getting the same output as you required because I have not taken care of the increasing order of the vertices because in re-indexing it does not matter. But you can modify it if you specifically want that.

**Also**, the output is not sorted because `unordered_map` does not store the keys in sorted order. If you want sorted keys, then use a `map` instead.

```
void reindexing(){
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

    unordered_map<int, int> mp;
    int to, from, i=0;
    double cost;

    // declaring a vector to store the reindexed edges
    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, double> > edges;

    while(cin>>from){
        // This loop runs till you are able to get vertices from input file
        cin>>to>>cost;

        // Now check if the vertices are already present in the unordered_map
        if(mp.find(to)==mp.end()){
            // If the control reaches here, then the vertex to is not found in map
            mp[to] = i++;
        }

        // similarly check for the from vertex
        if(mp.find(from)==mp.end()){
            // If the control reaches here, then the vertex to is not found in map
            mp[from] = i++;
        }
        edges.push_back({{mp[from], mp[to]}, cost});
    }
    
    // Printing the re-indexed vertex values
    for(auto it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++){
        cout<<it->second<<" - "<<it->first<<endl;
    }

    //... further processing of edges vector to build adjacency matrix
}
```

```
Output:
2 - 5
0 - 3
3 - 8
1 - 1
```

Comment: Thank you soooo soo much! The flow is so easy to understand as well! The order doesn't  matter, so long as you can reindex them bc some test cases for edges will be extremely large numbers. The way I had it set up would not work with those large numbers and I was completely stuck. Thanks again risingStark ;)!!!

Comment: @jakk0lantern I am glad that it helped you. You can consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)